# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] en mi paginación

Tags: nodejs, express, sequelize

Esto es parte de una paginación, y cuando tengo la base de datos vacía me tira el error, pero cuando tengo datos no me registra ningún error y me funciona correctamente.

Tengo esa misma consulta en otra parte mi código pero sin la parte de `page` y `pages`, solo el `findCountAll`,`limit` y `offset` y ahí no tengo problemas, por lo cual pienso que el error entra en conflictos en la lógica de esos bloques de `page` y `pages`, pero no encuentro qué puede ser.

```
exports.jobs = async (req,res,next)=>{
    // crear paginación, 8 por página
    let page = req.query.page ? Number(req.query.page) : 1
    let limit = 8
    const offset = (page-1) * limit

    let empleos = await Empleos.findAndCountAll({
        limit,
        offset
    })
    let count = empleos.count
    empleos = empleos.rows

    let pages = Math.ceil(count / 2);

    if(page > pages){
        res.redirect('?page='+encodeURIComponent(pages))
    }else if(page < 1){
        res.redirect('?page='+encodeURIComponent('1'))
    }


    let iterator = (page-5) < 1 ? 1 : page - 5
    let endingLink = (iterator + 9) <= pages ? (iterator + 9) : page + (pages - page)
    if(endingLink < (page+4)){
        iterator -= (page + 4) - pages
    }
    if(!empleos) {
        return next()
    }else{
        res.render('jobs',{
            titleHero: 'Empleos',
            figcaptionHero: 'Ofertas Laborales en la Zona',
            empleos,page,iterator,endingLink,pages
        })
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEMA**

En tu lógica tienes un condicional para determinar el valor de la variable `page`:

```js
if(page > pages) {
    res.redirect('?page='+encodeURIComponent(pages))
} else if(page < 1) {
    res.redirect('?page='+encodeURIComponent('1'))
}
```

Si se cumple alguna de éstas dos condiciones, se envía una respuesta al cliente:

```js
res.redirect(...);
```

Pero luego, tu función se sigue ejecutando, y dependiendo de lo que ocurra en las siguientes lineas, se ejecutará bien el llamado a `next()` o el llamado a `res.render()`.

Esto es lo que causa el problema o error:

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] ...

Ya que si se ha cumplido previamente alguna de las condiciones anteriores, ya se habrá enviado una respuesta al cliente.

Recordemos que las peticiones `HTTP` sólo pueden ser respondidas una vez, es decir, no puedes enviar más de una respuesta a la misma solicitud.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una solución es usar un retorno temprano ([*early exit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming#Early_exit)) dentro del condicional previo (y preferiblemente cada vez que llamas a algún método que signifique pasar el control a otro middleware (`next()`) o responder al cliente con un método del objeto Response (`res`)).

Por ejemplo:

```js
if(page > pages) {
    return res.redirect('?page='+encodeURIComponent(pages)); // <- early exit
} else if(page < 1) {
    return res.redirect('?page='+encodeURIComponent('1')); // <- early exit
}
```

Esto hará que la función termine en esa linea y no se producirá el envío de una segunda respuesta por la ejecución del código que aparece más adelante en tu función.

Comment: Hola! gracias por responder, no conocía el concepto, apliqué lo que mencionaste pero me da error, en este caso me da lo siguiente: 
` 
 code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
[0]     errno: 1064,
[0]     sqlState: '42000',
[0]     sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-8, 8' at line 1",

tambien en la consulta me menciona que tengo parametros indefinidos.

`

Comment: pero en otras ocasiones no me muestra nada de errores y en la consola veo que se hace la consulta a la base de datos un montón de veces como un bucle y la página web se detiene mostrando un mensaje de : ** La página localhost te ha redirigido demasiadas veces. **

Comment: Ese error es totalmente diferente al planteado en la pregunta original, te sugiero que realices una nueva pregunta con dicho error, en donde expliques el problema, la versión de Node, la base de datos utilizada y la versión del driver de conexión. Saludos